# Oracle 12c Rename datafile from Windows to Linux

Tags: oracle

[Img rename error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiWlO.png)

> SQL> select name from v$datafile;
>
> NAME
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- D:\ORACLEWINDOW\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF
> D:\ORACLEWINDOW\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSAUX01.DBF
> D:\ORACLEWINDOW\ORADATA\ORCL\UNDOTBS01.DBF
> D:\ORACLEWINDOW\ORADATA\ORCL\USERS01.DBF
>
> SQL> alter database rename file 'D:\ORACLEWINDOW\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF' to '/home/oracle/xyz/SYSTEM01.DBF';
>
> alter database rename file
> 'D:\ORACLEWINDOW\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF' to
> '/home/oracle/xyz/SYSTEM01.DBF'
>
> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-01511: error in renaming log/data files
>
> ORA-01516: nonexistent log file, data file, or temporary file
> "D:\ORACLEWINDOW\ORADATA\ORCL\SYSTEM01.DBF" in the current container

I want to rename datafiles and redo log files from endian windows to linux endian. Hope to help!

Comment: Do both of those directories exist on the machine? Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: I guess you migrate your database from Windows to Linux server. Maybe better run an export and import (`expdp` / `impdp`) at new server.

Comment: @Jon Heller: I have all datafile of windows endian in directory /home/oracle/xyz: 
ls /home/oracle/xyz/
CONTROL01.CTL  REDO01.LOG  REDO02.LOG  REDO03.LOG  SYSAUX01.DBF  SYSTEM01.DBF  TEMP01.DBF  UNDOTBS01.DBF  USERS01.DBF

Comment: SQL> select status from v$instance; --> MOUNTED

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controlfile to trace, rename logfiles and execute it like this: https://dbsguru.com/solution-for-ora-01516-nonexistent-log-file-data-file-or-temporary-file-in-oracle/

However, redo application is not supported between Linux and Windows except with a standby database. If you want to restore DB from windows to linux using RMAN, the backup must be a cold (consistent) backup, which requires no redo application.

See note "Restore From Windows To Linux using RMAN Fails (Doc ID 2003327.1)"